# Passing variable as selector for an object's property in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm having a bit of a problem that's probably going to have a stupidly simple solution which I'm missing.

I'm passing a `formField` here to a function which I'm them using to update a parameter in an object in an array.

The problem I'm finding though is that I'm currently able to select the item in the array from the index, but then when I try and select the property (let's say `op` in this example) using the variable I'm not able to get it

Just was wondering what I'm missing and if it's possible to pass a variable as the selector for the object's property?

```js
    async function updateFilter(id, formField, value){
        const indexNum = filterArray.map(item => item.id).indexOf(id);
        if (indexNum !== -1) {
            filterArray[indexNum].formField = value;
        }
        console.log(filterArray);
    }
```

[image: Using variable as selector for array object property]

Comment: `filterArray[indexNum][formField] = value;`

Comment: @Phil Why post an answer as a comment?

Comment: @Mike because I closed this as a duplicate. The comment addresses OP's specific code problem

Comment: @Phil Ah sorry. I didn't see it as being closed when I went to the question. Now I see it after refreshing.

Comment: Thank you - that got me there! 